# Mysql query return rows based on multiple column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this

```
Post_ID  KEY    Value
1       year   2014
1       month   09
2       year   2014 
2      month    10
3       year   2014
3       month   09
```

In this table  I have post_id , key (which indicated year and month of the post)  and value (which represents the year value and month value )

I want to return all the post_ID which is published "2014" and Month is "09"  ,that means I have value 1 and 3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd count how many properties match this specification and filter their `count` with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT   post_id
FROM     my_table
WHERE    (key = 'year' AND value = '2014') OR
         (key = 'month' AND value = '09')
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks it works , but what is the meaning "HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2" in this query ?

Comment: The `having` clause is a condition applied **after** the grouping. So, basically, this query selects all the posts with year=2014 or month=09 and counts how many matches there were per post. If there were 2, it means both conditions were satisfied, and that's a post you'd want to return.